# Check if paragraph has value with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I want to check in the checkbox only those that have no value in the paragraph. I don't know where I made a mistake in the code, but when I click the button (Value > 0), it marks all the checkboxes. Where is the mistake?

```js
$("input[id*='btnValue']").click(function() {
  var checked = !$(this).data('checked');
  if ($("p[id*='pCompanyValue']").val() == "") {
    $("input[id*='chkCustomer']").prop('checked', checked);
    $(this).data('checked', checked);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-content" style="background-color:#f2f2f2;">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Select customers:</h4>
    <table class="DataTable" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="CellNameButton"><input id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl00_chkAllCustomers" type="checkbox" name="ctl06$repCustomers$ctl00$chkAllCustomers" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl06$repCustomers$ctl00$chkAllCustomers\',\'\')', 0)"></td>
          <td class="CellNameButton"><span id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl00_Label7" class="CasualBold">Company name</span></td>
          <td class="CellNameButton"><span id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl00_Label1" class="CasualBold">Value</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl01_chkCustomer" type="checkbox" name="ctl06$repCustomers$ctl01$chkCustomer" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl06$repCustomers$ctl01$chkCustomer\',\'\')', 0)">
          </td>
          <td id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl01_trCompanyName" class="CellValue" valign="center">
            <p id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl01_pCompanyName" class="casual">random</p>
          </td>
          <td id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl01_trCompanyValue" class="CellValue">
            <p id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl01_pCompanyValue" class="casualRight">
              48.438,00</p>
          </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <input id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl02_chkCustomer" type="checkbox" name="ctl06$repCustomers$ctl02$chkCustomer" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl06$repCustomers$ctl02$chkCustomer\',\'\')', 0)">

          </td>
          <td id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl02_trCompanyName" class="CellValue" valign="center">
            <p id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl02_pCompanyName" class="casual">random2</p>
          </td>

          <td id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl02_trCompanyValue" class="CellValue">
            <p id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl02_pCompanyValue" class="casualRight">
              0,00</p>
          </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <input id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl03_chkCustomer" type="checkbox" name="ctl06$repCustomers$ctl03$chkCustomer" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl06$repCustomers$ctl03$chkCustomer\',\'\')', 0)">

          </td>
          <td id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl03_trCompanyName" class="CellValue" valign="center" style="background-color:#fff0e0;">
            <p id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl03_pCompanyName" class="casual">Random3</p>
          </td>
          <td id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl03_trCompanyValue" class="CellValue" style="background-color:#fff0e0;">
            <p id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl03_pCompanyValue" class="casualRight">
            </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <table class="modal-body">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="CellNameButton">
            <input type="submit" name="ctl06$btnValue" value="Value > 0" id="ctl06_btnValue">
          </td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="ctl06$btnConfirmCustomers" value="OK" id="ctl06_btnConfirmCustomers" class="CasualForm" check="true">
  </div>
</div>
```

Unnecessary: This code is done in asp.net that's why it's generated like this with stupid id names.

Comment: Paragraphs don't have values, they have text.

Comment: Even though I put .text() it doesn't help me at all because it still shows the same thing.

Comment: `$("p[id*='pCompanyValue']").text()` will get the text of the first paragraph whose ID begins with `pCompanyValue`. If you want a specific paragraph you need to give the actual ID rather than a pattern.

Comment: If you want to test if any paragraphs have empty text, use `.filter()` and check the length of the result. Also, you should use `.text().trim()` to ignore surrounding whitespace.

Comment: Maybe you should be looping over all the paragraphs, checking if that paragraph is empty and then checking the corresponding checkbox.

Comment: @Barmar *get the text of the first paragraph* - worse, it will get all of them and combine into a single text https://jsfiddle.net/qrxme0ca/ `$("p#pCompanyValue").text()` would give the first of them (but it's a partial ID, so that's probably not relevant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can make checked only those check-boxes which do not have a value.

```js
$("input[id*='btnValue']").click(function() {
  $("p[id*='pCompanyValue']").each(function () {
    var checkId = $(this).attr("id").replace("pCompanyValue", "chkCustomer");
    if ($(this).text().trim().length > 0) {
      $("#"+checkId).attr("checked", true);
    }
  });  
});
```

Comment: Yes, it works but now that I wanted to put it in my code, it didn't work anymore. here's exactly what Html code looks like now. I'll leave it below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the code looks like now. I don't know why it won't work again.

```js
$("input[id*='btnValue']").click(function() {
  $("p[id*='pCompanyValue']").each(function() {
    var checkId = $(this).attr("id").replace("pCompanyValue", "chkCustomer");
    if ($(this).text().trim().length > 0) {
      $("#" + checkId).attr("checked", true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-content" style="background-color:#f2f2f2;">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Select customers:</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="thisone" class="modal-body" style="max-height: calc(100vh - 210px); overflow-y: auto;">

    <table class="DataTable" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="CellNameButton"><input id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl00_chkAllCustomers" type="checkbox" name="ctl06$repCustomers$ctl00$chkAllCustomers" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl06$repCustomers$ctl00$chkAllCustomers\',\'\')', 0)"></td>
          <td class="CellNameButton"><span id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl00_Label7" class="CasualBold">Company name</span></td>
          <td class="CellNameButton"><span id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl00_Label1" class="CasualBold">Value</span></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <input id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl01_chkCustomer" type="checkbox" name="ctl06$repCustomers$ctl01$chkCustomer" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl06$repCustomers$ctl01$chkCustomer\',\'\')', 0)">

          </td>
          <td id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl01_trCompanyName" class="CellValue" valign="center">
            <p id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl01_pCompanyName" class="casual">RANDOM</p>
          </td>

          <td id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl01_trCompanyValue" class="CellValue">
            <p id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl01_pCompanyValue" class="casualRight">
              48.438,00</p>
          </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <input id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl02_chkCustomer" type="checkbox" name="ctl06$repCustomers$ctl02$chkCustomer" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl06$repCustomers$ctl02$chkCustomer\',\'\')', 0)">

          </td>
          <td id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl02_trCompanyName" class="CellValue" valign="center">
            <p id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl02_pCompanyName" class="casual">RANDOM</p>
          </td>

          <td id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl02_trCompanyValue" class="CellValue">
            <p id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl02_pCompanyValue" class="casualRight">
              0,00</p>
          </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <input id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl03_chkCustomer" type="checkbox" name="ctl06$repCustomers$ctl03$chkCustomer" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl06$repCustomers$ctl03$chkCustomer\',\'\')', 0)">

          </td>
          <td id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl03_trCompanyName" class="CellValue" valign="center" style="background-color:#fff0e0;">
            <p id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl03_pCompanyName" class="casual">RANDOM</p>
          </td>

          <td id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl03_trCompanyValue" class="CellValue" style="background-color:#fff0e0;">
            <p id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl03_pCompanyValue" class="casualRight">
            </p>
          </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <input id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl04_chkCustomer" type="checkbox" name="ctl06$repCustomers$ctl04$chkCustomer" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl06$repCustomers$ctl04$chkCustomer\',\'\')', 0)">

          </td>
          <td id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl04_trCompanyName" class="CellValue" valign="center" style="background-color:#fff0e0;">
            <p id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl04_pCompanyName" class="casual">RANDOM</p>
          </td>

          <td id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl04_trCompanyValue" class="CellValue" style="background-color:#fff0e0;">
            <p id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl04_pCompanyValue" class="casualRight">
            </p>
          </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <input id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl05_chkCustomer" type="checkbox" name="ctl06$repCustomers$ctl05$chkCustomer" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl06$repCustomers$ctl05$chkCustomer\',\'\')', 0)">

          </td>
          <td id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl05_trCompanyName" class="CellValue" valign="center" style="background-color:#fff0e0;">
            <p id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl05_pCompanyName" class="casual">RANDOM</p>
          </td>

          <td id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl05_trCompanyValue" class="CellValue" style="background-color:#fff0e0;">
            <p id="ctl06_repCustomers_ctl05_pCompanyValue" class="casualRight">
            </p>
          </td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <table class="modal-body">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="CellNameButton">
            <input type="submit" name="ctl06$bntValue" value="Value > 0" id="ctl06_bntValue">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="ctl06$btnConfirmCustomers" value="OK" id="ctl06_btnConfirmCustomers" class="CasualForm" check="true">
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT** I found a mistake. I went to Google and found a site that compared two Html codes and in the second I wrote *bntButton* instead of *btnButton*.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).